Наклон оси вращения объекта
y - высота, x - ширина, z - длина. α - угол поворота объекта по оси X (плоскость zy), β - угол поворота объекта по оси Y (плоскость zx). Вращение объекта по оси X осуществляется путем добавления cos(α) к существующей x координате, и sin(α) к существующей y координате, по оси Y - добавления -sin(β) к x координате и -cos(β) к z координате соответственно. Направление объекта определяется как (x: -sin(β)*cos(α), y: sin(α), z: -cos(β)*cos(α)). Таким образом, допустим объект повернут на 30° по оси X. Каким образом осуществить поворот объекта по оси Y на 180° чтобы угол наклона по оси X стал 0° при 90° по оси Y и 330° при 180° соответственно? Т.е. требуется создать формулу по которой объект мог бы вращатся по оси, являющейся наклоном оси Y по оси X.

По традиции объекты вращают вокруг осей X, Y, Z. Что такое вращение вокруг YX и ZX не понятно.

Плоскости, на которых лежат оси вращения. Считайте что YX - это X, а ZX - это Y по Эйлеру.

Точно? Звучит скорее так, будто вращение в плоскости XY вокруг оси Z.

Прочитайте https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0, переделайте обозначения в традиционные, задайте вопрос, если вам что-то будет непонятно.
